# Excel VBA XML HTTP - Code not working on Windows 8

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest, web-scraping

I have the following function which returns HTML document for the URL passed. I am using the returned HTML Doc in some other function.

The function works perfectly on Windows 7 but NOT on windows 8 unfortunately. How can I write code which works on Windows 7 and 8 both? I think I need to use a different version of XML HTTP object.

```
Function GetHtmlDoc(ByVal URL As String) As Object
    
    Dim msg As String
    
      ' Reset the Global variables.
        PageSrc = ""
        Set htmlDoc = Nothing
        
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", URL, True
            .Send
                                
            While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
            a = .statusText
            
          ' Check for any server errors.
            If .statusText <> "OK" Then
              ' Check for WinHTTP error.
                'msg = GetWinHttpErrorMsg(.Status)
                'If msg = "" Then msg = .statusText
                
              ' Return the error number and message.
                GetPageSource = "ERROR: " & .Status & " - " & msg
                Exit Function
            End If
                            
          ' Save the HTML code in the Global variable.
            PageSrc = .responseText
        End With

      ' Create an empty HTML Document.
        Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        htmlDoc.Open URL:="text/html", Replace:=False
            
      ' Convert the HTML code into an HTML Document Object.
        htmlDoc.write PageSrc

      ' Terminate Input-Output with the Global variable.
        htmlDoc.Close

      ' Return the HTML text of the web page.
        Set GetHtmlDoc = htmlDoc
        
End Function
```

Example function call:

```
Set htmlDoc = GetHtmlDoc("http://www.censusdata.abs.gov.au/census_services/getproduct/census/2011/quickstat/POA2155?opendocument&navpos=220")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XMLHTTP` no longer likes accessing remote servers from local scripts, switch to `ServerXMLHTTP`:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
```

(Using `False` performs the operation synchronously ngating the need for the `readyState` loop.)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But it gives an error message on Windows 8. Here is the screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7gzonuQsNbvQ2JNTnkxTUFOa2s/edit?usp=sharing Can you please have a look at it?

Answer (score -1):

I had same error turns out my code was working fine, just firewall blocked Excel so it failed.